# how to get no data message in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, error-handling, message

I am using some condition in where clause. for some condition some o/p data will come and for some there will not b any o/p data. so when there will b no o/p data I want to print a msg like "No data Available" ..... how can do that?

here is my query ......

```
SELECT
     "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNAME",
     "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTNAME",
     "ORDERDETAILS"."QUANTITYORDERED",
     "ORDERS"."STATUS"
FROM "ORDERS" 
INNER JOIN "CUSTOMERS" ON "ORDERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER" = "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER"
INNER JOIN "ORDERDETAILS" ON "ORDERS"."ORDERNUMBER" = "ORDERDETAILS"."ORDERNUMBER"
INNER JOIN "PRODUCTS" ON "ORDERDETAILS"."PRODUCTCODE" = "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTCODE"
WHERE "CUSTOMERS"."CITY" = ${LoadCity} AND "ORDERS"."STATUS" = ${LoadStatus}
```

Comment: that's better handled on the client side

Comment: Im using pentaho 5.2 report designer sql query console so none of the ans is working for me. anyway thanks everybody ......

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below Query if You want to do it in Databse side only otherwise you may do it in your Front end tool

```
Declare @count INT

SELECT
     @count=Count("CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNAME")
FROM "ORDERS" 
INNER JOIN "CUSTOMERS" ON "ORDERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER" = "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER"
INNER JOIN "ORDERDETAILS" ON "ORDERS"."ORDERNUMBER" = "ORDERDETAILS"."ORDERNUMBER"
INNER JOIN "PRODUCTS" ON "ORDERDETAILS"."PRODUCTCODE" = "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTCODE"
WHERE "CUSTOMERS"."CITY" = ${LoadCity} AND "ORDERS"."STATUS" = ${LoadStatus}

IF @count>0
Begin
   SELECT
    "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNAME",
    "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTNAME",
    "ORDERDETAILS"."QUANTITYORDERED",
    "ORDERS"."STATUS"
   FROM "ORDERS" 
   INNER JOIN "CUSTOMERS" ON "ORDERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER" = "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "ORDERDETAILS" ON "ORDERS"."ORDERNUMBER" = "ORDERDETAILS"."ORDERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "PRODUCTS" ON "ORDERDETAILS"."PRODUCTCODE" = "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTCODE"
   WHERE "CUSTOMERS"."CITY" = ${LoadCity} AND "ORDERS"."STATUS" = ${LoadStatus}
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'NO DATA AVAILABLE...'
END
```

**Edit:** Otherwise you may use the query like

```
Declare @Temptbl Table
(
CUSTOMERNAME Varchar(250),
PRODUCTNAME Varchar(250),
QUANTITYORDERED Int,
STATUS Varchar(50)
)

Insert into @Temptbl(CUSTOMERNAME,PRODUCTNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,STATUS)
SELECT
    "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNAME",
    "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTNAME",
    "ORDERDETAILS"."QUANTITYORDERED",
    "ORDERS"."STATUS"
   FROM "ORDERS" 
   INNER JOIN "CUSTOMERS" ON "ORDERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER" = "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "ORDERDETAILS" ON "ORDERS"."ORDERNUMBER" = "ORDERDETAILS"."ORDERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "PRODUCTS" ON "ORDERDETAILS"."PRODUCTCODE" = "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTCODE"
   WHERE "CUSTOMERS"."CITY" = ${LoadCity} AND "ORDERS"."STATUS" = ${LoadStatus}
IF (Select Count(*) from @Temptbl)>0
Begin
   Select * from @Temptbl
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NO DATA AVAILABLE...'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

use **Exists** to Check The data is avail or not

```
if exists (SELECT
    1
   FROM "ORDERS" 
   INNER JOIN "CUSTOMERS" ON "ORDERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER" = "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "ORDERDETAILS" ON "ORDERS"."ORDERNUMBER" = "ORDERDETAILS"."ORDERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "PRODUCTS" ON "ORDERDETAILS"."PRODUCTCODE" = "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTCODE"
   WHERE "CUSTOMERS"."CITY" = ${LoadCity} AND "ORDERS"."STATUS" = ${LoadStatus})
begin
 SELECT
    "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNAME",
    "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTNAME",
    "ORDERDETAILS"."QUANTITYORDERED",
    "ORDERS"."STATUS"
   FROM "ORDERS" 
   INNER JOIN "CUSTOMERS" ON "ORDERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER" = "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "ORDERDETAILS" ON "ORDERS"."ORDERNUMBER" = "ORDERDETAILS"."ORDERNUMBER"
   INNER JOIN "PRODUCTS" ON "ORDERDETAILS"."PRODUCTCODE" = "PRODUCTS"."PRODUCTCODE"
   WHERE "CUSTOMERS"."CITY" = ${LoadCity} AND "ORDERS"."STATUS" = ${LoadStatus}
end
else
 begin
 PRINT 'NO DATA AVAILABLE...'
end
```